# Error Code: 0x800f0954 installing .net framework 3.5 on windows 11 (Solution)

Tags: windows, .net-framework-version

If you are using Window 11, Then you will must face the above error. The solution is below:
Please follow the following steps in Answer Section:

Answer (score 0):

How To install .NET 3.5 in Windows 11

1. First Mount the Windows 11 iso in your file manager
2. Now Download cmd file from HERE
   Link :- https://www.newrechargetricks.in/2021/06/windows-11-net-error-how-to-install-net.html
3. Then simply run the netfx.cmd file as an administrator
4. Wait for a while and it will automatically install that .NET 3.5 in your Windows 11
5. After installing the .NET it will ask you to press any keyboard button
6. Simply press and the cmd window will be closed and your .NET 3.5 is now successfully installed
7. You can verify it by going to the windows features section in the control panel